# Whats the process to adding a Public Key for the merchant?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

Good day, we are creating a Vodacom product mini-app, we have created our public and private keys.. We don't see an option to view merchant details. Could you assist us with the process needed to add our public key for our merchant app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an email to miniprogramsupport@vodacom.co.za to get your public key configured on the VodaPay systems.

Comment: thank you, we did as you mentioned and the process has been started..